# im trying to do password strength in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to do password strength in angular, with uppercase,lower
case, number, and special character in angular in the console I'm getting
error as.

> NullInjectorError: No provider for password strength! in passwordstrength.ts file

HTML

```html
    <div class="validation_errors text-left">
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validationmessages.password">
                              <div class="error-message"
                                *ngIf="loginform.get('password')?.hasError(validation.type) && (loginform.get('password')?.dirty || loginform.get('password')?.touched)">
    
                                <span> {{ validation.message }}</span>
                  <p class="help is-danger"
                  *ngIf="loginform.get('password')?.hasError('strong')">
                  Must have at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter.</p>
                              </div>
                            </ng-container>
                          </div>
```

ts

```typescript
     this.loginform = this.formbuilder.group({
              username: ['', Validators.required],
              password: ['', passwordstrength.strong]
            });
          }
```

password strength.ts

```typescript
  import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export interface ValidationResult {
    [key: string]: boolean;
}

export class passwordstrength {

    public static strong(control: FormControl): ValidationResult {
        let hasNumber = /\d/.test(control.value);
        let hasUpper = /[A-Z]/.test(control.value);
        let hasLower = /[a-z]/.test(control.value);
        // console.log('Num, Upp, Low', hasNumber, hasUpper, hasLower);
        const valid = hasNumber && hasUpper && hasLower;
        if (!valid) {
            // return what´s not valid
            return { strong: true };
        }
        return null!;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can  you post the full contents of password strength.ts file?

Comment: please check it now. first i wrote, return null it saying error as Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ValidationResult'. so I changed it to return null! now I'm getting error in console

Comment: please share other code if you have  for checking password strength even that would be helpful

Comment: you need to add the passwordstrength to the providers either in AppModule.ts or the component module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use @Injectable() decorator for your service class.

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class passwordstrength {
    // class definition
}
```

The other option is to specify it in the providers array of your module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [ ],
  providers: [passwordstrength],
  bootstrap: [ ... ]
})
```

Other comments from [Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-02):

> Do use dashes to separate words in the descriptive name.
> Do use conventional type names including .service, .component, .pipe, .module, and .directive.

So, your "password strength.ts" can be changed to "password-strength.service.ts"

Similarly, "class passwordstrength" can be changed to "class PasswordStrengthService"

Comment: actually its typing mistake in here i not gave any spaces in file

Comment: @bhargavkumar Ok, if the above solution fixed your problem, can you mark it as accepted?